# HH: MM in Range Bar

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I use [Ermodo Range Bar](https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar),  and the fact that I need to display a minimum value and a maximum value in hours and minutes ... That is below:

[image]

```
public class FilterActivity extends Activity {
private RangeBar rangebar;
final int SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.filter_layout);

final TextView mDepartMin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDepartMin);
final TextView mDepartMax = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDepartMax);
rangebar = (RangeBar) findViewById(R.id.rangebar1);
rangebar.setTickCount(25 * SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
rangebar.setTickHeight(0);
rangebar.setThumbRadius(8);
rangebar.setConnectingLineWeight(3);

mDepartMin.setText("" + (rangebar.getLeftIndex() / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION) + ":" + SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (rangebar.getLeftIndex() % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION));
mDepartMax.setText("" + (rangebar.getRightIndex() / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION) + ":" + SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (rangebar.getRightIndex() % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION));

rangebar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onIndexChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftThumbIndex, int rightThumbIndex) {
        int minHour = leftThumbIndex / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION;
        int minMinute = SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (leftThumbIndex % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
        int maxHour = rightThumbIndex / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION;
        int maxMinute = SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (rightThumbIndex % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
        mDepartMin.setText(minHour + ":" + minMinute);
        mDepartMax.setText(maxHour + ":" + maxMinute);
    }
});
}
}
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

I think date or calendar class may help, but how do I use them?

I need it to be displayed as HH:MM instead of H:M

Comment: read `android.text.format.DateUtils` docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DecimalFormat` you can achieve.

```
DecimalFormat deciFormat= new DecimalFormat("00");
mDepartMin.setText(deciFormat.format(minHour) + ":" + deciFormat.format(minMinute));
```

OR **Using Calendar**

```
mDepartMin.setText(getFormattedDate(minHour,minMinute));
```

Call this below method

```
public static String getFormattedDate(int hour, int minute) {
    Calendar cale = Calendar.getInstance();
    cale.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cale.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    return dateFormat.format(cale.getTime());
}
```

Comment: That is not the right way to do it, you need to use calendar or date class.

Comment: @KakshilShah did you see his code.. he is not using `Calendar` or `Date` instance.. and the main thing is calculation of `minHours`, `minMiute` etc...

Comment: Yes, and he should use two dates(Having just time) and use that to point to min and max.

Comment: @KakshilShah its not only about Calender/Date to get 2 digits. He need to use `SimpleDateFormat` also because  `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` it never returns  9AM as 09. it returns 9 only.. check and let me know.

Comment: @KakshilShah please check

Comment: @OmaSydykov updated with Calendar API if in case you need.